# Rails How to add an instance variable to dropdown selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

From Ruby Docs -->

```
select_tag "count", raw("<option>1</option><option>2</option>")
# => <select id="count" name="count"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
```

How would I populate these options with instance variables? For example ...

```
<%= form_with model: @event, url: predict_path,  method: :post do |form| %>
 <%=select_tag "predict", raw("<option><@event.f1></option><option><@event.f2></option>")%>
 <%= form.submit %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp ... a  couple more minutes of browsing docs and I found my answer.

https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionView%2FHelpers%2FFormTagHelper:select_tag

```
<%=select_tag "count", options_for_select([@event.f1, @event.f2])%>
```

---

EDIT

---

Ths above answer fixed that issue but gave me many other issues along the way.

As max said, it's better to stick to form_with and form helpers.

Final final answer:

```
<%= form.select :count, [@event.f1, @event.f2] %>
```

Comment: Thats the documentation for Rails 4.1. The official Rails api documention is available on https://api.rubyonrails.org/ and you should start out by reading the [guides article on the  form helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). Using the low level tag helpers like `select_tag` is almost always the wrong answer to whatever you are doing. Use `form_with` and the form helpers that are bound to a form builder instead.